# Help Identifying Wiring Harness

Tags: wiring, part-identification, electronic-control-module, corvette

I need to find out what this goes, the year and I think it’s to a corvette eco and wiring harness but don’t know for sure Help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Unfortunately, an out-of-focus picture which does not show the complete harness will make identification much more difficult and perhaps impossible. Your question would be improved with a better pictures, and whatever information you have that leads to you think it comes from a Corvette.

Comment: I was told it was for a corvette but that’s why I’m on here because I don’t know for sure

Comment: I added some more photos that are clearer I hope please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the part number your ECM, so I can't tell for sure, but it appears to be an ECM for a 94-97 Corvette LT1. Mind you, I believe the other vehicles which used the LT1 (Camaro, Firebird, Caprice) all used the same ECM, so it could be for one of them as well. If you take the cover off of the ECM, there will be a part number exposed. You can use that to verify what it actually came off of. As far as the wiring harness, if you can mate it to the ECM, more than likely it is for an LT1, too ... but who knows if it is for a Corvette or one of the other vehicles I mentioned. It can most likely be retrofit to work for any of the vehicles, but may not be an exact fit.

So you know, I did a [Google search for **1994 Corvette ECM**](https://www.google.com/search?q=1994+Corvette+ECM) and visually verified it is the same one. If you bought this to fit a 1994-1997, it will probably work. You'll most likely need to have a tune put on it so it matches your engine exactly. Different years used different engine parameters. This ECM will not work for the 92-93 LT1 Corvette because it had a completely different ECM in it. It will not work for 98 and newer Corvettes (I'm thinking maybe not even the 97) because they came with the LS1 engine, which is completely different.